# Problems with Angular Http module

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, angular5

I am getting that error on trying to launch my app.

```
ERROR 
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ApiUserService -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ApiUserService -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
Stack trace:
_NullInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1218:19
resolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1516:17
tryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1458:16
StaticInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1326:20
resolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1516:17
tryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1458:16
StaticInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:1326:20
resolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:11070:12
NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12303:16
resolveDep@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12793:12
createClass@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12655:29
_createProviderInstance@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12632:20
createProviderInstance@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12473:12
createViewNodes@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13945:53
createRootView@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13847:5
```

I don't know how to fix that, the error seems to be in my ApiUserService,

https://gist.github.com/LarsE343/4fe09a513e4d0d77564a4b0eac30b8e2 //link to the ApiUserService Gist [Complete File]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and how to create a [mcve]: please post _all_ of the relevant code (including your main module, probably called `app.module.ts`) and details in the question itself. I've code-formatted the error for you, for readability, and cut the last part of the error since the relevant part, like most stack traces, is right at the top. Thanks!

Comment: Also, about _"when I launch my app"_ there are many ways to start an angular application. What exactly did you launch: `ng serve` or something else?

Comment: When you get an error message you should search/google that error message. That is what they are there for, to guide you to the root of whatever problem is occurring. In this case the error is `NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient`. If you had googled that you would have seen the above proposed duplicate, it was the 1st returned result.

Comment: If you are still stuck you will have to post your code by creating an [mcve]. See also [ask].

Comment: My advice is more general about how to ask a good question, but @Igor's advice is crucially important, and comes before even asking here.

Comment: Hey, ty for your nice answer, it works now :) ty

Comment: If my answer worked for you please mark it as the accepted answer, cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here, but try to add HttpClientModule:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 

imports: [
  HttpClientModule
]
```

I'm guessing you forgot to add that to your `app.module.ts`.